# setVisible='gone' on react-native

Tags: image, react-native, visibility

```
<Image source={require('../img/Image.png')}
 style={{flex: 1, resizeMode: 'stretch'}}/>
```

How can I make this Image gone after 3 seconds in react-native?

Answer (score 0):

Use set timeout and state to hide your element.

```
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {hide: false};
}

...

componentDidMount(){
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        hide: true
      })
    }, 3000);
}
```

Then in your render:

```
{
this.state.hide == false ?
<Image source={require('../img/Image.png')}
 style={{flex: 1, resizeMode: 'stretch'}}/>
:
null
}
```